# LaTeX(3) - Floating point number - Unit tests?

Tags: floating-point

How are floating point macros tested?

Are comparisons made with other libraries not implemented in `LaTeX(3)'?

Is the IEEE standard for floating point arithmetic respected?

Comment: Do you mean how are they tested routinely or where do the test values come from, or both?

Comment: My question is about the respect of the IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic.

Comment: it is  IEEE 754, but decimal not the more common double binary floating point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The test suite for `expl3` is used to test the FP code. The system works by comparing the result of running one or more functions with a 'certified' set of results.<sup>*</sup> As such, routine testing of the FP results is based on having pre-calculated from an external source.

The reference values for the FP calculations were carried out by [Bruno Le Floch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2707/bruno-le-floch) when he wrote the current code in around 2011. Bruno didn't note down the source of the values in the commit logs, but there are many ways to obtain IEEE 754 compliant values. For example, in Lua one can use

```lua
print(string.format("%.16g", <calculation>))
```

to generate comparison values. One can also use higher-precision systems and round down: Wolfram Alpha is a readily-accessible approach.

---

<sup>*</sup> When the tests were written, we were using a simple Perl script for log comparison and batch files/Make for the back-end. Since then, we've moved to `l3build`, which is capable of generating comparison results on-the-fly. So it would be possible to use an external tool, most readily Lua, to generate the 'correct' results. However, that would simply slow the testing down without really adding much.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This will help me in my very small projects.

Comment: er your Lua is showing use of  IEEE 754  double (binary floating point)  l3fp implements  IEEE 754  decimal floating point

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well yes, but the idea is to have a 'good enough' comparison: in the end, after all, this is all approximation (hence Knuth's position on floating point values in TeX ...)

Comment: Maybe my day job is affecting the view, but there is a lot of differece between asking if the arithmetic is good enough and asking if it implements a specific numeric model (such as ieee double)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess I see it as 'in the end any real value is only ever 'good enough' for some value of 'enough'.

Comment: @JosephWright if you are measuring physical quanties, as in, say, Chemistry, then yes. But if you are adding up pennies as 1/100 of a pound the fact that you can do exact decimal arithmetc and only approximate binary is a real difference in behaviour,

Comment: @JosephWright Do you have a link to these tests? The `l3build` doc is very dry.

Comment: @projetmbc https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb43-1/tb133wright-l3build.html covers `l3build` for beginners; the tests are visible at https://github.com/latex3/latex3/tree/main/l3kernel/testfiles (look for the `m3fp<name>.lvt` files).

Comment: Great! This will save me time.

Comment: @JosephWright *"`l3build` for beginners"* is a great material. Thanks for this article.

Comment: @JosephWright What is the method used to validate, or exclude, values in the log file written by `\fp_log`? I would like to specify expected results directly in a test file, as is done in conventional unit tests. What is the way to do this with `l3build`?

Comment: @projetmbc Well I'd just check the `.tlg` , but if you want to have an assertion-type check, you could do something like `\str_if_eq:eeTF { \fp_eval:n { <calc> } } { <ref-value } \TRUE \ERROR \NEWLINE` to check that the result of the evaluation, and do that inside `\TESTEXP`; that will log just a series of `TRUE` statements. If you want a fuller demo, probably best to post a separate question - I think that's a different question to the one here.

Comment: @JosephWright I will come back with concrete things related to my future small packages (this should start in June this year). Thanks for all!

Answer (score 9):

l3fp implements IEEE 754 *decimal* arithmetic (which has been part of [IEEE 754 since 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754))

The precision is broadly equivalent to the better known IEEE "double precision" *binary* arithmetic, but results can differ.

For example 0.1 can be stored exactly as a decimal float but not as a binary. This enables examples such as

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\def\foo{ceil(2.00 - (0.90 + 0.50 + 0.45 + 0.15))}

\directlua{
ceil=math.ceil
print(string.format(
  "\string\n Lua : \@percentchar.32g", \foo))}

\typeout{l3fp: \fpeval{\foo}}

\end{document}
```

which produces

```
Lua : 1

l3fp: 0
```

so a difference of exactly 1 which will not vanish if you round the values to higher precision.

The mathematically correct value here is 0 as returned by l3fp, but the Lua value is not in error it is the value mandated by double arithmetic. (Essentially showing a programming error naively: applying `ceil` converts a tiny rounding error in to a difference of 1, but using decimal arithmetic has no rounding error here.)

Apart from implementation issues using decimal arithmetic is good for typical typesetting tasks like adding up money or exam scores where users can be surprised to get percentages totalling 99.99998 if they fail to round appropriately.

Comment: Here is an interesting post : https://www.alanshawn.com/tech/2020/08/03/l3fp-accuracy.html .

Comment: One of the main gaps in my implementation of IEEE 754 decimal is that I don't keep track of the exponent: IEEE requires distinguishing 0.1 (namely 1×10^{-1}) from 0.100 (100×10^{-3}) and tracking this in calculations.